# label separator between the section number and title to 0pt

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm writing my thesis using mitthesis class. However, the numbering of the sections and subsections is not what I want. Right now my document has this numbering, but the 0 in X.0.X and X.0.Y should not be there. How can I fix that?
Currently:
Chapter 1 
Introduction
Section
1.0.1 subsection
1.0.2 subsection

Should be:
Chapter 1 
Introduction
Section
1.1 subsection
1.2 subsection
My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{acknowledgments}
%\include{contents}
%\setcounter{page}{3}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\appendix
%\include{appa}
%\include{appb}
\include{bib}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve it. I searched but I could not find the most relevant solution one to solve my problem.
P.S. I am really new working with LaTex.
thanks

Comment: You have not shown any relevant code but I assume you are using `\chapter` and `\subsection` but not `\section` or `\section` and `\subsubsection` but not `\subsection`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, indeed. This user posted the contents of one of the included files in a non-answer posted a number of hours ago, and a misunderstanding of the sectioning hierarchy was the cause.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. inside chap1, I was using \subsection instead of \section. like this:
\chapter{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem Statement}
and now I did as you said.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using `\chapter` and `\subsection` but not `\section`.

The middle `0` is the section counter which is still at 0 as there has not been a `\section` command.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed it like what you said. now it works well. thanks